# make clickable button for specified number of times

Tags: jquery

How can I make a button to be clickable for the specified number of times that I can script in code suppose I have the following jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/syZ78/)

```
$('h3').on('click', function(){
    $('#test').css('width','+=10px');
});
```

but it is clickable for any times. Now I want to do clickable just once or two times. How can I do that?

> I have demonstrated the example with css width += but actually I want to do for
>
> click for what time == as I define

**Edit**

next question: Okay now I have two buttons one is h3 and another is h4.

when h4 is clicked  then reset the time for h3 and when h3 is clicked reset time for h4

Comment: put a counter in that case to stop at specific click event.

Comment: create a static counter that increments in the function. once it has reach the limit, disable the click event.

Comment: Your question was answered in several different forms by several different people.  You shouldn't change it once there are answers.

Comment: I was about to edit my question right after asked my question but with net disturb I was slow to do that which I'm gone negatively....so sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cnt = 0;
$('h3').on('click', function () {
    if (cnt != 2) {
        $('#test').css('width', '+=10px');
        cnt++;
    }
});
```

or if you want it to only click once you can use .one()

```
$('h3').one('click', function () {
        $('#test').css('width', '+=10px');
});
```

**Update**

```
var h3cnt = 0;
var h4cnt = 0;
$('h3').on('click', function () {
    if (h3cnt != 2) {
        $('#test').css('width', '+=10px');
        h3cnt++;
    }
    h4cnt =0;
});
$('h4').on('click', function () {
    if (h4cnt != 2) {
        $('#test').css('width', '-=10px');
        h4cnt++;
    }
    h3cnt =0;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/syZ78/1/)

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Do you want to reset the click or add one extra click if you click h4 vica versa?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar That's great, now you edited question with a completly different behaviour, GL with that...

Comment: reset h3 if h4 is clicked and reset if h4 if h3 is clicked

Comment: @NavinRauniyar ask a question when you know what you are looking for, not before, Thank You!

Comment: I'm so sorry for that my net was a little disturbed so edit was slow.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar That's ok! NP

Answer (score 3):

```
$('h3').data('clickable',2).on('click.h3', function(){
    this.clicks = !this.clicks?0:this.clicks++;
    if(this.clicks < $(this).data('clickable'))
        $('#test').css('width','+=10px');
    else $(this).off('click.h3');
});
```

Comment: @MackieeE ^^^ This - please explain.

Comment: Nevermind, Apologies ;) Up-voting never the less =)

Answer (score 2):

This will stop the click event functioning after 5 clicks...

```
var count = 5;

$('h3').on('click', function(){
    count--;
    if (count == 0) return;
    $('#test').css('width','+=10px');
});
```

Just change `count` to suit.

Comment: Maybe OP wants each h3 to be clickable X times

Comment: @A.Wolff - Yep, that's exactly why I upped your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(function() {
    var countA = 3,  // number of clicks that the h3 will work for
        countB = 5;  // number of clicks that the h4 will work for

    $('h3').on('click', function(){

        countB = 5;  // reset count for h4

        if (!countA) {return;}
        countA--;

        // do stuff

    });

    $('h4').on('click', function(){

        countA = 3;  // reset count for h3

        if (!countB) {return;}
        countB--;

        // do stuff

    });



})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$('h3').attr('data-count', 1).on(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        var count = $(this).attr('data-count');
        var maxClicks = 5;

        count = parseInt(count, 10);

        if(count >= maxClicks)
        {
            return
        }

        $('#test').css('width','+=10px');
        $(this).attr('data-count', count + 1);
    }
);
```

Here si the example too:

http://jsfiddle.net/merianos/sPKVr/

And this is your code updated :

http://jsfiddle.net/merianos/syZ78/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can take a count variable and increment count each time the button is pressed ,and when count reaches a specified number disable the button,,simple